# Mongodb aggregation with mongoose filter embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working with NodeJS and mongoose and making an aggregation of two collections:

collection 1 (stations):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
    "marca" : "x",
    "modelo" : "xx",
    "fabricante" : "x",
    "id_station" : [ 
        191, 
        457
    ],
    "sensor_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : 2,
            "type" : "clima",
            "place" : "interior",
            "img" : "assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun" : "Hum. Relativa",
            "medida" : "%",
            "interfaz" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "name" : 3,
            "type" : "clima",
            "place" : "interior",
            "img" : "assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun" : "Hum. Relativa",
            "medida" : "%",
            "interfaz" : ""
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccacc61a0160f16c50f5a1b"),
    "marca" : "y",
    "modelo" : "yy",
    "fabricante" : "y",
    "id_station" : [ 
        999
    ],
    "sensor_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : 2,
            "type" : "clima",
            "place" : "interior",
            "img" : "assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun" : "Temperatura",
            "medida" : "%",
            "interfaz" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "name" : 3,
            "type" : "clima",
            "place" : "interior",
            "img" : "assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun" : "Hum. Relativa",
            "medida" : "%",
            "interfaz" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Collection 2 (measures):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc29612bda12f1f16ac600"),
    "id_station" : "191",
    "attrName" : 2,
    "attrType" : "float",
    "attrValue" : 21,
    "recvTimeTs" : 1554134471,
    "recvTime" : "2019-04-01T16:01:11.000Z"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc2a852bda12f1f16ac6b1"),
    "id_station" : "191",
    "attrName" : 3,
    "attrType" : "float",
    "attrValue" : 2222,
    "recvTimeTs" : 1554134499,
    "recvTime" : "2019-09-01T16:01:11.000Z"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc3a7d2bda12f1f16acc34"),
    "id_station" : "999",
    "attrName" : 33,
    "attrType" : "float",
    "attrValue" : 2222,
    "recvTimeTs" : 1554134499,
    "recvTime" : "2019-09-01T16:01:11.000Z"
}
```

When the aggregation is done, the document that is completely embedded in the collection is shown and I need to show only the document that matches the attrname.

How can I perform a search inside the embedded document? Is it possible to just show that information?

I would need sensor_type to only show the information of the name: 33 since it is its real value on 2 when the embedded document shows that data and is erroneous.

code with error:

```
    {
   "DatagreenhouseRecuperado":[
      {
         "_id":33,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5ccacc61a0160f16c50f5a1b",
               "marca":"Metos",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Metos",
               "id_station":[
                  999
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Temperatura",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":33,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":33,
               "attrValue":8888,
               "recvTimeTs":1588524826,
               "recvTime":"2020-05-03T18:53:46"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      }
   ]
}
```

The goal is this:

```
{
   "DatagreenhouseRecuperado":[
      {
         "_id":33,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5ccacc61a0160f16c50f5a1b",
               "marca":"Metos",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Metos",
               "id_station":[
                  999
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":33,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":33,
               "attrValue":8888,
               "recvTimeTs":1588524826,
               "recvTime":"2020-05-03T18:53:46"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
     function getDataSensorGreenhouseLastDataPruebas(req, res) {
        var array = req.params.nombresensores;
        var id_station = array.split(',');
        var array2 = req.params.sensores;
        //var sensor = array2.split(',');
        // var id_station = req.params.id_station;
        console.log('id_station: ' + id_station);
        Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "id_station": { "$in": [191, 999] }, "attrName": { "$in": [2, 33] } } },
            { "$sort": { "recvTime": -1 } },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$id_station",
                    "latest": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "id_station": "$latest.id_station",
                    "attrName": "$latest.attrName",
                    "attrValue": "$latest.attrValue",
                    "recvTimeTs": "$latest.recvTimeTs",
                    "recvTime": "$latest.recvTime"
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "station_types",
                    "localField": "id_station", // local field in measurements collection
                    "foreignField": "id_station", //foreign field from sensors collection
                    "as": "sensor"
                }
            },
            { "$unwind": "$sensor" },
            // { "$match": { "sensor.sensor_type.name": 2 } },
            {
                "$addFields": {
                    "sensor.attrName": "$attrName", // Add attrName to the sensors
                    "sensor.attrValue": "$attrValue", // Add attrValue to the sensors
                    "sensor.recvTimeTs": "$recvTimeTs",
                    "sensor.recvTime": "$recvTime"

                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$id_station", // Group by time
                    "medidas": { "$push": "$sensor" }, // Collect measurements
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 } // Count measurements
                }
            },

        ], (err, DatagreenhouseRecuperado) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' + err })
            if (!DatagreenhouseRecuperado) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })
            console.log('Ordenado: ' + JSON.stringify(DatagreenhouseRecuperado));

            /*DatagreenhouseRecuperado.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (a._id - b._id)
            })*/
            res.status(200).send({ DatagreenhouseRecuperado })
        })
    }
```

Greetings and thank you.

EDIT 01 **Solution**

Hello this is the adaptation to the code:

```
{
        "$addFields": {
            "sensor.attrValue": "$attrValue", // Add attrValue to the sensors
            "sensor.attrName": "$attrName", // Add attrValue to the sensors
            "sensor.recvTimeTs": "$recvTimeTs", // Add attrName to the sensors
            "sensor.pruebas": "$name_comun", // Add attrName to the sensors
            "sensor.sensor_type": {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$sensor.sensor_type',
                    as: 'shape',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$shape.name', '$attrName'] },
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

the problem is that in sensor_type it shows a data and not all the information of that object. How can I add the other fields?

Comment: A couple of questions. First - why run second unwind stage? You can run a match on an array without unwinding it,  Second question, why not use let and pipeline in lookup? So all of that can be nice an clean

Comment: Hi, I did not know that you could make a match in an array without displaying it. with the other the same thing happens to me.

Comment: Hello, the main problem I have is that sensor_type shows everything that contains the embedded document and not the ID information

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly, looking on what you wrote above, and what you wrote in comments. You want to "project" the data differently and show only name field, or you are saying you are missing _id?

Comment: In sensor_type you must show the sensor information that matches the attrName with the name. Now show all the embedded document. For example if the attrName is 33 inside sensor_type it will only show name information: 33. Not the 2 as it happens now. I understand that it is understood.

Comment: Hello, I have the version 3.6.

I have modified the code closer and closer to what I need. updated in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, all the code is correct, what you did in that lookup is match all sensors, that inside sensor_types array have one with the name of "XX". And lookup did its job, it returns all matches, but those arrays have additional documents. When you match subdocument, it will not filter it for you.

Just filter them in $project, or in your $addFields add the following

```
"sensor.sensor_type": {
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$sensor.sensor_type",
        "as": "sensorType",
        "cond": { "$eq": ['$$sensorType.name', 33]}
    }
 }
```

Another thing you can do, is change your $lookup to have let and pipeline, inside this pipeline, do the match and project the data. This is much cleaner and nicer approach. I'll update the answer with this example as well later in the day.

Comment: thanks for the help, I am testing the solution by adding the code inside addfiels and it gives me this error Use of undefined variable: sensorType "

Comment: Hello,

I still trying to find a solution some help?

Comment: @Manolait check updated code, I was missing filter, thought you would figure that out on your own

Comment: Hello, I have modified the post, I have a problem when I make a filter, it only shows a value and not the whole object of the embedded document

Comment: I have already solved the problem, is putting in the input sensor.sensor_type.name and for this reason only that value came out.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Np, do some research about $lookup with let and pipeline, You will be able to group a lot of this code and it will be easier to read and understand.